# Windows Search - how to index desktop shortcuts

Tags: windows, windows-search

How do I configure Windows Search to index shortcuts on my desktop that *are not* in the Start menu? C:\users\myusername\Desktop *is* amongst indexed locations.

Comment: Here we are 13years later, windows 10 STILL NOT ABLE TO SEARCH THROUGH THE 10 ICONS I HAVE ON DESKTOP

Answer (score 1):

This should work for **Windows 10**.

1. Click on the **Windows key**.
2. Type **Indexing Options** and click enter.
3. Click **Advanced**.
4. Click **File types**.
5. Add **`.lnk`** as a new file type.
6. Click **OK**.

Make sure your desktop is amongst indexed locations.

Comment: Do you mean `.ink` or `.lnk`?

Answer (score 1):

I suffer the same problem, here I found a work around: you can drag the shortcut icon from desktop to "Start" button, then it will create a new item in "Start" menu. Every time you search, the item will be listed in result.

Comment: As a side note, the "start menu" should be included in the search index. This approach works pretty well for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're using Windows 7 so in order to change Windows Search Index, just do the followings:
1) Press '**Windows Key**' and type '**Indexing Options**', you will **Indexing Options** in the search result; let choose it

2) Now you will see **Indexing Options** windows, let choose **Modify**

3) When '**Indexed Locations**' appears, let choose a customize location which containing your shortcuts or your files, etc .. in the 'Change selected locations' panel; when you've done, just press 'OK' to continue.

4) Windows Search *does indexing immediately*; indexing time depends on your data, just press 'Close' and let Windows Search runs in background.

5) Fire up Windows key, and try a new search.

Comment: See my question, Desktop is amongst indexed locations already.